# Is it possible to run VMWare Server on a Linux VPS?

Tags: vmware-server, vps, xen

I want to run a Windows Server 2003 under a Debian Linux VPS I have.  Is this possible using VMware Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost certainly no: Most VPS solutions are /already/ virtualized (***Virtual*** Private Server), many of them using [Xen](http://www.xen.org) or similar.  Even if it "worked" (that is the hypervisor actually started) performance would be abysmal - likely to the point of being unusable.

Comment: +1. Performance would be terrible.